# Wordpress isn't generating image thumbnails for image size over 1 MB

Tags: wordpress

I have a developed a wordpress website by installing a pre-developed theme from themeforest.net. When i try to upload an image, the image successfully uploads but the preview/ thumbnail isn't generated only for file sizes over 1 MB. The max file size i can upload is 8MB. Please Help!

I tried uploading increasing memory and execution caps. Nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

You're not giving a lot of information, so I'm suggesting a work around.

Reduce the size of your images with cropping them to the needed size. Compress JPG and PNG images.

[Online Image Compression](https://tinypng.com/)

Comment: Hi @DoomCrystal I have already compressed to image from 46MB to 1.6 MB, Can you specify what information you need from me? I will be happy to share.

Comment: How do you know that it has to do with file sizes? Is there an error message? In what resolution are your images? What are you using the thumbnails for?

Comment: I tried uploading the image with size less than 1 MB and it uploaded successfully.

Comment: However i updated some parameters in the server settings and it worked perfectly fine. Thanks for providing your valuable time.